# How to extract x509 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I have the following script. It connects to a TLS server and extracts some X509 data such as validity dates and public-key. I have the following script:

```
import socket, ssl
import OpenSSL

hostname='www.google.com'
port=443

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=hostname)
ssl_sock.connect((hostname, port))
ssl_sock.close()
print("ssl connection Done")

cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((hostname, port))
# OpenSSL
x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
pk = x509.get_pubkey()
print(x509.get_notAfter())
print(x509.get_notBefore())
print(pk)
```

The problem is that the validity dates and the public-key are returned in unreadable format. How to solve this issue? i.e get the validity in date format and the public-key in hex format?

Also, how can I save the certificate file in my local disk for reference?

**EDIT:**
This is the output I am getting:

```
b'20170223141600Z' 
b'20161201141600Z' 
<OpenSSL.crypto.PKey object at 0x0000019EBFDF73C8>
```

Comment: What's unreadable?

Comment: Could that be YYYYMMDDHHMM formatted date?

Comment: What do you mean: "public-key in hex format" ?

Comment: I mean I need to print the public-key as hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 18):

The date returned is a YYYYMMDDHHMM formatted date. You can convert it to a datetime object with:

```
datetime.strptime(x509.get_notAfter().decode('ascii'), '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')
```

Comment: Thanks. But to get the point, let me know how to get the public-key and how to save the file locally.

Comment: The server key **is** the public key. Just write it to a file

Comment: That's not correct. I want the key in a hex. format. How to convert that format to hex? and I want to save the x509 certificate to  a file.

Comment: ok, it sounds like you you're the expert. What format do you want the key / certificate in? And which encoding?

Comment: I need the key in hexadecimal foramt and the cert in human readable text format (don't know what type of encoding but need it to be saved in the hard disk fro reference).

Comment: Like I said, save the server key. Convert it to hex if you wish

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify with code how to save the server key?

Comment: I assume the date timezone is UTC? Am I correct?

Comment: @Luv33preet The trailing Z indicates it's Zulu time, aka UTC. According to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.5.2, the date field could contain a timezone offset, so it would probably be best to expect it.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get the certificate, why are you using the `get_pubkey` method ?

Public keys and certificates aren't the same.

To get the certificate :

```
buffer = dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, x509)
print(buffer.decode())
```

That will give you the base64 content of the certificate.

You will need to manually add the header

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

and the footer

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```