# How to get ssl information formatted in dataframe for multiple domains?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ssl, openssl

How to get these stats in a dataframe for multiple domains. ex : google.com , nyu.edu

expected_output :

```
name            expiry date                                   status 

google.com      Wednesday, 12 August 2020 at 17:30:48         active
nyu.edu         expired/No Cert                               expired/No Cert
```

tried this :

```
import ssl, socket
import pandas as pd

hostname =['google.com','nyu.edu']
datas=[]

for i in hostname:

    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    with ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=i) as s:
        s.connect((i, 443))
        cert = s.getpeercert()
        issued_to = subject['commonName']
        notAfter=cert['notAfter']

        data=[{"name":issued_to},{"expiry":notAfter}]

        datas.append(data)


df = pd.DataFrame(datas)
```

Tried this got this can't figure out which certs are expired and which are not.

Comment: Check if the expiry date is before today? The `datetime` module is probably what you're looking for...

Comment: my code is popping error, if alt name is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `getpeercert()` you won't be able to retrieve the certificate in the outpout if the verification failed (you can test with https://expired.badssl.com/ for example).

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480084/2614364), an alternative is to use `getpeercert(True)` to get he binary outpout of the certificate and parse it using OpenSSL.

In the following example, I've added an `expiry` column to check whether the certificate has expired by comparing with the current date :

```
import ssl, socket
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import OpenSSL.crypto as crypto

hostname = ['google.com','nyu.edu','expired.badssl.com']
datas = []
now = datetime.now()

for i in hostname:
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    with ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname = i) as s:
        s.connect((i, 443))
        cert = s.getpeercert(True)
        x509 = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1,cert)
        commonName = x509.get_subject().CN
        notAfter = datetime.strptime(x509.get_notAfter().decode('ascii'), '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')
        notBefore = datetime.strptime(x509.get_notBefore().decode('ascii'), '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')
        datas.append({
            "name": commonName, 
            "notAfter": notAfter,
            "notBefore": notBefore,
            "expired": (notAfter < now) or (notBefore > now)
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(datas) 
print(df)
```

Output :

```
           name            notAfter           notBefore  expired
0  *.google.com 2020-08-12 12:00:48 2020-05-20 12:00:48    False
1       nyu.edu 2021-01-06 23:59:59 2019-01-07 00:00:00    False
2  *.badssl.com 2015-04-12 23:59:59 2015-04-09 00:00:00     True
```

Note that I've used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41121732/2614364) to convert timestamp formatted date to datetime

Also, if you want to test invalid certificates, you can check https://badssl.com/ for a list of testing domain which could arise specific verification error